# How to run the whole project in GoLand?

Tags: go, ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

I have a small project with several .go files. When I run main.go only this compiles but nothing else, so my application crushes. I understand that I have to change settings in Run -> Edit Configurations, but don't know what to do exactly. IDE also doesn’t see terminal pre-compiled package, so "Package" option instead of "File" doesn't work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To run the whole project you have to go *Run* -> *Edit Configuration*, set *Run Kind* to *Package* and type in field *Package* your project directory name.

Comment: After finding this solution via Google, I had no luck because I kept trying to type `client` under _Package_ to compile all files under `~/go/src/reponame/src/client`. Turns out that my _Package_ should instead say `reponame/src/client` for it to work.